# Python 3 can't use installed packages

Tags: python, macos, pip

After installing the *ics* package with *pip3* in my terminal on *Mac OS High Sierra*. I can't use this package in *Python 3.6*. I installed it by using:

```
pip3 install --user ics
```

When doing this again, I get the following message:

```
Requirement already satisfied: ics in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: six>1.5 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from ics)
Requirement already satisfied: arrow==0.4.2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from ics)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from ics)
```

But when I try to run a script using:

```
python3 test.py
```

I get the following error:

```
from ics import Calendar, Event
ImportError: cannot import name 'Calendar'
```

The *test.py* file just contains an import of the package:

```
from ics import Calendar, Event
c = Calendar()
```

It is not the first time that I can't use an installed package with *Python 3* on my Mac. I looked at a couple of solutions, like updating the `.bash_profile` file, but that already pointed at the correct Python version I was using.

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.6
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

This issue is frustrating me for days right now and I can't seem to find any solution..

Comment: Have a look into virtualenv. You can create a new isolated environment to install packages into for this project.

Comment: Make sure when running your script you are using same python version. Alternatively you can `import pip` and install package via script to make sure it's installed for same python `pip.main(['install', '--user', 'ics'])` There is also ImportError you can catch it and install package if it not exist, than import again.

Comment: Could you: a) try only `import ics` b) make sure that `print(sys.path)` includes `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages` and that `import ics` followed by `print(ics.__file__)` also prints that folder?

Comment: @Zydnar first of all, thanks for your help! Unfortunately, I already checked if the Python versions were the same. And using your code to install the package inside my script, returns the same message that the requirements are already satifsfied..

Comment: Is `ImportError: cannot import name 'Calendar'` all that it says in the error message?

Comment: Try to uninstall and install package, maybe it can't be imported because it's incomplete.